# if there is a fragment not in backstack, fragment added before it didn't appear again when pop the stack

Tags: android, android-fragments

step1: click `addNewFragmentBtn` add a new fragment`[A]` and add it to backstack

step2: add another fragment`[B]` which is not in backstack

step3: click `addNewFragmentBtn` add a new fragment`[C]` and add it to backstack

step4: click back btn back to previous fragment.

The whole progress shoulde be `A->B->C-B->A`, if i continue click the back button after step4, the back stack entries's counts  reduced  but the fragment A is not revisible.
How can i re attach the fragment A?

```
        public class Main extends FragmentActivity {
        private int i=1;
        private int j=1;
        public FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            final View addNewFragmentBtn = findViewById(R.id.add_new_fragment);
            final View backBtn = findViewById(R.id.back);
            final View addNewFragmentNotInStackBtn = findViewById(R.id.add_new_fragment_not_in_stack);

            addNewFragmentBtn.setOnClickListener(
                    new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                            FragmentSample fragment = new FragmentSample();
                            Bundle args = new Bundle();
                            args.putString("key1", "fragment1-" + i + "is in backstack");
                            fragment.setArguments(args);
                            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.content, fragment);
                            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                            fragmentTransaction.commit();
                            i++;
                        }
                    }
            );
            addNewFragmentNotInStackBtn.setOnClickListener(
                    new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                            FragmentSample fragment = new FragmentSample();
                            Bundle args = new Bundle();
                            args.putString("key2", "fragment2-" + j + " is not in backstack");
                            fragment.setArguments(args);
                            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.content, fragment);
    //                        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                            fragmentTransaction.commit();
                            j++;
                        }
                    }
            );
            backBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int backStackEntryCount = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
                    if (backStackEntryCount > 0) {
                        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                    } else finish();
                }
            });

        }
    }
```

Comment: Try to add your Fragments by `ft.replace()` instead of `ft.add()`.

Comment: @owe I want resume the first fragment A when user click back button skip the B , so B should not replace A

Comment: this will be handled by your backstack automatically. If you add FragA and than FragB and click than on backbutton -> FragA should appear. But it's necessary that you add each fragment to your backstack by `ft.addToBackStack()`.

Answer (score 0):

here is my workaround:
I classify them with tags: a kind of fragment which you want put in back stack give them a tag "A_STACK" ,the others which you don't wish to resume, add a tag "B_STACK".

in the BackBtn.onClick method:

```
    public class Main extends FragmentActivity {
        private int i = 1;
        private int j = 1;
        public FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
        private final static String NO_HISTORY_FRAGMENT = "NO_HISTORY_FRAGMENT";
        private final static String KEEP_HISTORY_FRAGMENT = "KEEP_HISTORY_FRAGMENT";
        public String KEEP_HISTORY_FRAGMENT_STACK = "KEEP_HISTORY_FRAGMENT_STACK";
        public String NO_HISTORY_FRAGMENT_STACK = "NO_HISTORY_FRAGMENT_STACK";

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);


            final View addNewFragmentBtn = findViewById(R.id.add_new_fragment);
            final View backBtn = findViewById(R.id.back);
            final View addNewFragmentNotInStackBtn = findViewById(R.id.add_new_fragment_not_in_stack);

            addNewFragmentBtn.setOnClickListener(
                    new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();


                            FragmentSample fragment = new FragmentSample();
                            Bundle args = new Bundle();
                            args.putString("key1", "fragment1-" + i + "is in backstack");
                            fragment.setArguments(args);
                            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.content, fragment, KEEP_HISTORY_FRAGMENT);
                            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(KEEP_HISTORY_FRAGMENT_STACK);
                            fragmentTransaction.commit();
                            i++;
                        }
                    }
            );
            addNewFragmentNotInStackBtn.setOnClickListener(
                    new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                            FragmentSample fragment = new FragmentSample();
                            Bundle args = new Bundle();
                            args.putString("key2", "fragment2-" + j + " is not in backstack");
                            fragment.setArguments(args);
                            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.content, fragment, NO_HISTORY_FRAGMENT);
                            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(NO_HISTORY_FRAGMENT_STACK);
                            fragmentTransaction.commit();
                            j++;
                        }
                    }
            );
            backBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int backStackEntryCount = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
                    if(backStackEntryCount>0){
                        FragmentSample currentFragment = (FragmentSample) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(NO_HISTORY_FRAGMENT);
                        if(currentFragment!=null){
                            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(NO_HISTORY_FRAGMENT_STACK, 1);//clear the not necessary fragment stack
                            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(KEEP_HISTORY_FRAGMENT_STACK, 0);//switch to the usefull stack
                        }else {
                            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                        }
                    }else finish();
                }
            });

        }
    }
```